# If React.js is the V, in the MVC, what are the other letters?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React but I'm still unsure on how to grow it up into a full-fledged app.

For the M and the C, what frameworks are cool to use with it? What if I want to go functional? Should I just use jQuery?

What about Routes, Ajax and the other things that many frameworks offers us?

Comment: "Find a framework" questions aren't generally a good fit for StackOverflow. I'd suggest you start: https://github.com/facebook/react/wiki/Complementary-Tools and see what fits your needs. If you have a specific implementation question about one of those, that's a much better fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually go simply for [Flux](http://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html) and [react-router](https://github.com/rackt/react-router)
Flux is based on the usage of Stores, Actions, and Dispatcher (depending on the implementation of Flux you use).

The Stores will play the role of the Models in an MVC framework.
The Controller (C) part is trickier to explain in the context of Flux, but it would be probably some of your React components that could be considered controller, combined with the Stores.

React-router makes it easy to manage routing in your React apps.

My more general advice would be to not look for "cool" frameworks to make your apps, but ask yourself what is going to be the fastest to implement with, the easiest to maintain and test, and what stack is going to be the simplest to do the job. Sometimes, simpler is much better.

Answer (score 1):

For the M part I think Play Framework has a very simple way to create models. Your controller implementation depends on how you want to do it but it would definitely be a mix of both front end javascript to transfer data from the view (if you plan on using ajax) and a back end component. Play would help you out with the backend part of the controller.