# Why ReactJS is Only V in MVC?

Tags: reactjs, model-view-controller

As a `ReactJS` developer we can do anything with `ReactJS`, as mentioned in the `react` official [blog](https://reactjs.org/blog/2013/06/05/why-react.html) it is only a **V**.

But the thing is `React` component has the controller which is controlling the events and user requests, even `this.state` can be the model like `$scope` in `Angular`.

Why can't we say this as a `MVC`?

May be I missed something, please clarify this part. Something is clear that `ReactJS` is not only for **V** (view)

Comment: Relevant: https://www.quora.com/If-React-js-is-only-the-V-in-the-MVC-what-will-be-the-M-and-C-if-you-use-React-Native and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904310/if-react-js-is-the-v-in-the-mvc-what-are-the-other-letters