# React (Redux + Redux Saga) and MVC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, model-view-controller, redux, redux-saga

Since React is regarded as View of MVC,

would Sagas considered as Controller and the Stores as Model?

Is React + Redux + Redux Saga MVC? I've read somewhere that they are different since Redux stricts the data flow to only one way.

Would React be considered as View? Saga as Controller? Redux as Model?

Edit: I'd like to clarify I would like to know if these consider as MVC and why/why not. Not which.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If React.js is the V, in the MVC, what are the other letters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904310/if-react-js-is-the-v-in-the-mvc-what-are-the-other-letters)

Comment: Actually, this question is about why/why not rather than what. The similar post doesn't answer my question, sadly.

Answer (score 3):

This is opinionated answer on how I have been using React/Redux/Sagas

> Would React be considered as View? Saga as Controller? Redux as Model?

IMO you can consider

- React as View
- Redux as Model
- Redux + Saga (combined) can be considered as Controller.

I have been using Saga to listen on action and perform side effects like calling API and once API data returns, sometimes I have been using Saga to process API response `data` and modify it as needed or perform another side effect and then emit new `action` with modified payload which will be consumed by Redux `reducer` to modify `state`. Most of the times how to manipulate data logic exits in Redux reducer.

Comment: This is exactly what my project structure looks like. I was quite unsure of it being MVC or not. Thank you. I'll wait for others to drop their opinions as well.